# Select second last element with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I already know of :last-child. But is there a way to select the div:

```
<div id="container">
 <div>a</div>
 <div>b</div>
 <div>SELECT THIS</div> <!-- THIS -->
 <div>c</div>
</div>
```

NOTE: without jQuery, only with CSS

Comment: Surely there's some logic as to why the second-last child is significant?

Comment: yes i need to select both last and second-last for applying some styles

Comment: why can't you just put a class on the 2nd last div

Comment: "why can't you just put a class on the 2nd last div": Perhaps if you get to style content that's being generated, in which you don't have (easy) access to add a class to the second last item?

Answer (score 387, accepted):

In CSS3 you have:

```
:nth-last-child(2)
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child

**nth-last-child** Browser Support:

> - Chrome 2
> - Firefox 3.5
> - Opera 9.5, 10
> - Safari 3.1, 4
> - Internet Explorer 9

Comment: solution in css:  #container > :nth-last-child(2) {background: red;}    Please check this codepen to see it in live : https://codepen.io/marc_dahan/pen/JyxObz

Comment: Now that we don't need to support older IE, this answer will work perfectly.
Honestly, if people are still using IE 8 and below, they don't deserve to have pretty things.

Answer (score 80):

***Note:** Posted this answer because OP later stated in comments that they need to select **the last two elements**, not just the second to last one.*

---

The `:nth-child` CSS3 selector is in fact more capable than you ever imagined!

For example, this will select the last 2 elements of `#container`:

```css
#container :nth-last-child(-n+2) {}
```

But this is just the beginning of a beautiful friendship.

- [`:nth-child` Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth)

```css
#container :nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div>a</div>
 <div>b</div>
 <div>SELECT THIS</div>
 <div>SELECT THIS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, my answer only selects the last-child minus 1. Didn't know about this. +'d

Answer (score 1):

This adds a comma after each LI, an ", or" after the second to the last LI, and a period to the last LI using pure CSS with nth-last-child()::after.

To affect just the second to the last LI delete the last CSS entry and set the second CSS entry's (n+3) content to empty ('').

```
`<style>
    /* Append endings to LIs.
       Append "," to all but the last 2 LIs.
       Append ", or" to the 2nd to the last LI. 
       Append "." to the last LI. */
    article li:nth-last-child(n + 2)::after {
        /* All but the last row. */
        content: ', or';
    }
    article li:nth-last-child(n + 3)::after {
        /* Overwrite all but the last two rows. */
        content: ',';
     }
     article li:nth-last-child(1)::after {
        content: '.';
     }
</style>
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
    <li>Line 4</li>
</ul>`
```

Yields

- Line 1,
- Line 2,
- Line 3, or
- Line 4.