# if last child OR second to last child

Tags: jquery

How can I target the second to last child in this example?

```
if( ($(this).is(":last-child")) || ($(this).is(":eq(-2)")) ) {
```

`:last-child` works for me but not `:eq(-2)`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select second last element with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418744/select-second-last-element-with-css)

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [:nth-last-child() selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/).

```
if ($(this).is(":last-child, :nth-last-child(2)"))
```

---

## nth-last-child selector

> **Description:** Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their
> parent, counting from the last element to the first.
>
> **jQuery( ":nth-last-child(index/even/odd/equation)" )**
>
> **index:** The index of each child to match, starting with the last one
> (1), the string even or odd, or an equation ( eg.
> :nth-last-child(even), :nth-last-child(4n) )
>
> **Version added:** 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).is(":nth-last-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try this code is working fine.

**Example**:

```
var abs = '<?php echo $this->getOrder()->getStatusLabel() ?>';
 //alert(abs);
 if(abs == "Delivery Complete"){
  //alert('Sucssess')
  var asscer = document.getElementsByClassName('form-buttons')[0].lastChild;
  asscer.style.display = "none";
  }
 if(abs == "Pending with OPS"){
  var asscer = document.getElementsByClassName('form-buttons')[0].lastChild.previousSibling;
  asscer.style.display = "none";
  //alert(asscer);

 }
```