# Conditional <li> appreance

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I created a responsive menu for my website. (Wordpress)

```
<nav id="main-nav" roll="navigation" class="main-nav">
                <ul id="menu" class="menu">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu' , 'menu' => 'Main Navigation' ) ); ?>
                    <li class="back"><a href="#header">back</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

I would like to add another `li` in the end of menu when users visit the website with iPhone!
So this is what I did:

```
<nav id="main-nav" roll="navigation" class="main-nav">
                    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu' , 'menu' => 'Main Navigation' ) ); ?>
                        <li id="hidden" class="menu"><a href="#">test</a></li>
                        <li class="back"><a href="#header">back</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

But eventually nav menu stopped working. Is there any way to add this conditional `li` ?
Any ideas?

Comment: Could it simply be that the (unique per page!) id "hidden" is used elsewhere as well? Or maybe a `<li>` of class `menu` does not fit in with the code?

Comment: That's a good suggestion with the id not being unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add it normally through your menu in wp admin. Then use an attribute selector to show/hide it in your CSS. If it is always the second last element, you could use `:nth-last-child(2)` borrowed from [Select second last element with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418744/select-second-last-element-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

Change the li to this:

```
    <li id="hidden" class="menu" style="display: none;"><a href="#">test</a></li>
```

Then put this in the javascript at the bottom

```
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        $('#hidden').show();
    }
```

This will work unless the user fakes the device their using and at that point they deserve to have a crappy looking website imo.

It's not the word press way of doing it though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to conditionally insert the li pair using wp_is_mobile(), e.g.,

```
<ul>
    <li>bing</li>
    <li>bam</li>
    <li>boom</li>
    <li>non-mobile last bullet</li>
    <?php if wp_is_mobile() { ?>
        <li id="mobile-bullet" >mobile-only last bullet</li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

and then if you'd like, style the mobile bullet so it stands out in the CSS

```
li #mobile-bullet {
    color: red;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

and then perhaps change the styling if in portrait mode using media queries

```
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    li #mobile-bullet {
        font-size: smaller;
    }
}
```