# Apply CSS conditionally to last list item without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say you have a list of items:

```
<li>abc</li>
<li>efg</li>
<li>hij</li>
```

You want the last item to be red, but only if there is more than one `<li>`, is that possible without JavaScript?

Comment: Firstly define color for `li:last-child` to and then for `li:first-child` set the color to inherit. or you can simply use `not(:first-child)`

Comment: This question has already has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418744/select-second-last-element-with-css

Comment: @KunJ웃 That question doesn't cover the conditional part of this question (ignoring the single `<li>` case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a selector for `the last but not the first child`?

```css
li:last-child:not(:first-child) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>  
  <li>three</li>    
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>alone</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using nth-child.

For example if you have an ordered list and you want to target the 2nd li you use the code as below:

```css
ul ol:nth-last-child(2){color:#ff0000;}
```

```html
    <ul>
    <ol>list 1</ol>
    <ol>list 2</ol>
    <ol>list 3</ol>
    <ul>
```

Once you run the code you will see the last child of the UL is colored red.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors, and you have different options to achieve this:

### Play with definitions order

Define `first-child` styles after defining `last-child`, so the `last-child` styles are overwritten by `first-child` styles.

```css
ul li:last-child{
  color: red;
}

ul li:first-child{
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First element</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>First element</li>
  <li>Second element</li>
  <li>Third element</li>
</ul>
```

### Use !important

Define `first-child` styles with `!important`, so they takes preference over `last-child` styles.

```css
ul li:first-child{
  color: inherit !important;
}

ul li:last-child{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First element</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>First element</li>
  <li>Second element</li>
  <li>Third element</li>
</ul>
```

### Use a selector with a heavier preference

`id` and `class` selectors in CSS have a heavier preference than tag selectors, so if you define the `first-child` with one of these, it will have more importance than the `last-child` who is defined in a tag selector.

```css
.list li:first-child{
  color: inherit;
}

ul li:last-child{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>First element</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li>First element</li>
  <li>Second element</li>
  <li>Third element</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS conditionals

As @george said on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43157038/4480868), you can simply use the CSS `:not()` conditional to check that the `last-child` isn't also `first-child`. That **is the best option for your specific case**.

```css
li:last-child:not(:first-child) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First element</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>First element</li>
  <li>Second element</li>
  <li>Third element</li>
</ul>
```