# How to change background color in odd/even div in descending order

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change background color odd or even in div, with compulsory last div in grey color, last before div in green color, the same as follow all div's.

```css
.main{
width:500px;
height: 500px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
.box{
width:300px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid red;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>


</div>
```

I try to change odd/even class in css, it is not meet my expectation.
In last div is compulsary grey color, last before is in green color.
Please any one guide, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your snippet so it shows what you actually tried? Namely swapping `even` and `odd`? Because that will of course produce exactly what you're looking for. Unless we're talking about an unspecified number of `.box` divs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select second last element with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418744/select-second-last-element-with-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - how to colour odd and even divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457564/css-how-to-colour-odd-and-even-divs)

Comment: Try my answer @Jegan

Answer (score 3):

You can use nth-last-child to solve what you need, see my below edits which solves your issue. More info on nth-last-child here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-child.asp

Thanks

```css
.main{
width:500px;
height: 500px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
.box{
width:300px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid red;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background:green;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}

.box:nth-last-child(2) {
  background:green;
}

.box:nth-last-child(1) {
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>


</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted, this answers his question with a working example correctly!

Comment: How your answer differs from `zmag`?

Comment: Check my answer @Justinas

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main{
width:500px;
height: 500px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
.box{
width:300px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid red;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background:green;
}

.box:last-child {
  background: grey;
}
.box:nth-last-child(2){
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
<div class="box">7</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something from the last row, Use `:nth-last-child()`.

```css
.main{
width:500px;
height: 500px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
.box{
width:300px;
height: 100px;
border:1px solid red;
}

.box:nth-last-child(odd) {
  background: grey;
}

.box:nth-last-child(even) {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select div using `nth-last-child`.
Try my code-

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box {
  width: 500pxpx;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box:nth-last-child(2n+1) {
  background: grey;
}

.box:nth-last-child(2n) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```