# how to pick 2nd last child by css

Tags: css-selectors

I want to select 2nd last-child.
which is the product, Kindly suggest me.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Setting</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
<li><a href="#">COntact US</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
ul li a{
color: black;
}
ul li a:nth-child(n-1) {
color:red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select second last element with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418744/select-second-last-element-with-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select second last element with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418744/select-second-last-element-with-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do:

```
li:nth-last-child(2) {
   css declarations;
}
```

nth-last-child counts back from the last child rather than forward from the first.

Note that I took out the 'ul' and 'a' selectors from the css. That didn't match what you had in the html.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. Really helpful